# Trying to Use Both Cabin and Baskerville Fonts in the Same Document

Tags: fonts, pdftex, font-encodings

In the following code, I invoke both the `cabin` and `baskervald` packages.

I am able to start off with the `cabin` font by simply specifying `\cabin`; however, when I want to begin using the `baskervald` font employing the same technique (the command is commented out in the MWE), I get an error.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\cabin
\lipsum[1]
\vskip 10pt
%\baskervald
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How may I call in the `baskervald` font for displaying the second paragraph (and selectively as well throughout a longer document)?  I have compiled the MWE with `pdflatex`.

Comment: as the documentation says, baskervald sets the default roman family to baskervald, so use simply \rmfamily. (cabin can be used with \sffamily).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your recommendation seems to work fine.